# int function not returning any values/core dumped in normal for loop

Tags: c, function, loops, cs50

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

void record_preferences(void);
int vote();

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
record_preferences();
}

void record_preferences(void)
{  
    int n = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        
        {
            string votes[4];
         votes[1] = get_string("Rank 1: ");
         votes[2] = get_string("Rank 2: ");              
         votes[3] = get_string("Rank 3: ");
         int p = vote();
            if(p==1)
            {
                printf("votes registered\n");
            }
            else if(p==2)
            {
                printf("one or more invalid votes\n.");
            } 
            else if(p==3)
            {
                printf("you have to choose 3 different candidates");
            }    
        }        
    }
}

//checks if the input votes are all present in the candidates array and if there are repeat votes
int vote()
{
    int argc;
    int verif;
    string votes[4];
    string argv[argc];

    //loop that verifies if all votes are valid
    for(int j=1; j<4; j++)
    {
        for(int k=1; k<argc; k++)
        {
            if(strcmp(votes[j], argv[k])==0)
            {
            int verif = 1;
            break;
            }
            else if(k==argc-1)
            {
            int verif = 2;
            int j = 4;
            }
        } 
    }
    //loop that checks for repeat votes
    for(int l=1; l<=3; l++)
    {
        for(int m=2; m<=3; m++)
        {
            if(l!=m && strcmp(votes[l], votes[m])==0)
            {
                int verif = 3;
            }
        }
    }
    return verif;
}`
```

I'm trying to code a tideman election system for cs50. This is my first time trying to work with user-made functions; all of my other projects were just bundled into main.

The function that is supposed to check if there are repeat or invalid votes isn't returning any values, and the loop that checks for repeat votes is causing segmentation fault (core dumped) even though I'm not going over the size of the array. Could it be that it's sometimes comparing strings to themselves?

I've tried bundling it all into `main` but the value of `verif` doesn't change, so I think it's either something to do with the formatting or something inside my loops' logic that isn't working.

Comment: `int verif = 3;` declares a new variable that shadows the `int verif` you declared at the top of your function

Comment: Similarly `string votes[4];` in `vote` has no knowledge or connection to the array of the same name in `record_preferences`

Comment: thanks so much for replying! it's supposed to shadow the old value if it detects repeated inputs. is that causing the segmentation fault? 
how do i connect the votes array in vote to the votes array in record_preferences?
do i have to declare the array before main?
if it's an empty array, shouldn't it be always returning 2? since an empty string would be detected as an invalid choice in the first loop

Comment: @brunomnt You should either pass them as parameters to functions, or declare them as global variables.

Comment: "_all of my other projects were just bundled into main_" Suggest you go back and re-work those assignments to use "functions"... Learning to use functions and parameters and variables was a large part of those early training assignments. There's no avoiding doing the hard part; all you might achieve is merely postponing the pain.

Comment: thanks for the insight, that's absolutely correct. i was made aware of the problem while looking at other submissions for the sets. I realized bundling arguments would lead to problems in the future, so i started trying to work with multiple functions in this project. Funnily, i thought having less stuff in my code just made it more efficient, which isn't untrue for these small projects, but I ended up not looking at the bigger picture. This is my first week, though, so i figure there's a lot to learn still.
Thanks for going out of your way to give me advice to improve, i appreciate that.

Comment: On another note, how do i change votes[4] to a global variable? i tried putting it on top of the code but it didn't change the inconsistencies between the arrays in different functions. i also tried setting votes[4] as the intake argument for int votes(). as expected, it didn't help, since that makes no sense, but i thought maybe maybe it would work somehow

Comment: I fixed it by doing 200 different things. it was ALL wrong. but i'm glad it worked out. thanks all for your help <3

Comment: I don't have cs50.h installed so I don't know if it somehow exports `argv` and `argc` as global variables that you use `vote()`.  As it your program doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @brunomnt You should write up your solution so others can benefit from it, or delete your question if you figured it out and no longer need help.

Answer (score 0):

I declared the variables whose value i wanted to be shared between functions as global variables, then set them as the parameters for the function call and gave them a new name in the function definition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).